# Creating a library in Kotlin multiplatform Library

Tags: maven, shared-libraries, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am very new to maven central and just started learning Kotlin multiplatform. I am trying to create a new library in KMM but I am not able to get a proper guide on how can I do that.

I have already gone through [this](https://dev.to/kotlin/how-to-build-and-publish-a-kotlin-multiplatform-library-creating-your-first-library-1bp8) links which shows how to create lib in KMM but i am not sure if this is what exactly I need.

Few questions which i currently have :-

- Is it necessary to create a Sonatype account to create KMM library ?
- Is there any other way I can publish my library other then maven central now as Jcenter is deprecated and jitpack still doesn't support KMM libraries.

Also it'll be great if you can suggest any other blogs or video tutorial to refer for publishing KMM library.

Comment: Hello! Are any of these questions still relevant to you? If so, I would like to address the first one. I mean, as far as I know, there is no direct need to have a Sonatype account if you're not aiming to publish it to Maven Central. Also, I would like to recommend you to read more about [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) Gradle plugin, as most of the publishing specifics come from it, not from KMM exactly.